# Should you abort all running threads in and Activity's onDestroy()

Tags: android, android-activity, xamarin.android, android-thread

I have an Activity which runs a number of separate downloading tasks on different threads. They are creating in onCreate() like this:

```
public override void OnCreate()
{
    base.OnCreate();
    workerThread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        InitialiseDownloads();
        foreach (DownloadingFile file in downloadingFiles)
            {
                Thread t = new Thread(file.StartDownload);
                threads.Add(t);
                t.Start();
            }
    });
    workerThread.Start();
}
```

Where a `List<Thread>` threads is filled with a new thread for every file to download.

If the activity is closed before these threads finish, will they keep running after the activity is killed if I don't abort them? If so, is this appropriate:

```
public override void OnDestroy()
{
    workerThread.Abort();
    foreach (Thread thread in threads)
    {
        thread.Abort();
    }
    base.OnDestroy();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no guarantee your `Thread` will be killed after `Activity` is destroyed. It may be killed right short after or it may stay alive as long as the OS allows it to. To make things worse, if you leak your `Activity` into your thread it won't be destroyed as long as the thread is running.

If you want your background task to survive even when `Àctivity` gets killed use a `Service`. To guarantee it's not killed by the OS you should start it in foreground - `startForeground`.

Comment: Thankyou, some great information here that I needed. In summary though, when I should include this onDestroy() method if I want all threads aborted and garbage collected as the Activity is?

Comment: @Moffen No problem. It depends on how you do the download. If you use `InputStream` for that then you could just close it once you no longer need it. If you download chunk by chunk then you could do it in a `while` loop with some `isDownloading` flag so that to set it to `false` when Àctivity` gets killed.